# Questions about architecture

Tags: 64-bit, package-management, 32-bit

So, I've been trying to learn as much as I can about linux operating systems, and something is currently confusing me.

uname -a

```
Linux L655 3.5.0-27-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 19:58:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Okay, so my system is x86_64, which means it is 32bit, correct? So, since it is 32 bit I can only install 32 bit programs. My confusion is over the fact when I was installing the google talk plugin, the i386 .deb didn't work and the amd64 did. Why?

Also, if I install a program with dkpg, will my other package managers (synaptic, software center, ect) know about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your questions one by one.

- **Okay, so my system is x86_64, which means it is 32bit, correct?**

  **No**. `x84_64` means that your system is 64 bit.

  For a 32 bit machine, the output of `uname -a` would be something like:

```
Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

While, as it is in your case, the output for 64 bit machine would be something like:

```
 Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 x86_64  x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- **My confusion is over the fact when I was installing the google talk plugin, the i386 .deb didn't work and the amd64 did. Why?**

  Since your computer is 64 bit, you should install the software packages built for 64 bit architecture. Ofcourse, if such packages are not available you can revert to 32 bit packages.
- **Also, if I install a program with dkpg, will my other package managers (synaptic, software center, ect) know about it?**

  Yes, they will.

  However you'd need to make sure that the sources in Ubuntu Software Center are correctly set. To do so:

  - Open *Ubuntu Software Center*.
  - Then go to *Edit* > *Software Sources*.
  - In the *Other Software* tab, make sure that the following are ticked:

  [image]